# Python + Django: Trouble with setting up mkvirtualenv on macOS

Tags: python, django, macos

I’m using macOS (10.13.3) and have installed Python v 3.6.4

I'm trying to follow the instructions per this Mozilla article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/development_environment

**My process:**

**1**  `which python` » `/usr/local/bin/python` *note, somewhere along the way I did a Symlink `ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python`*

---

**2**  `python3 -V` » `Python 3.6.4`

---

**3**  `sudo -H pip3 install virtualenvwrapper` »

```
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenvwrapper in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: stevedore in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied: pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
```

---

**4**  `nano .bash_profile` » *Add following:* »

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
# export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 # No impact
# export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3 # No impact
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python # No impact
# VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=`which python` # No impact
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

---

**5**  `source ~/.bash_profile`

---

**6**  `mkvirtualenv my_django_environment` »

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python
Using base prefix '/usr/local/bin/../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6'
New python executable in /Users/myuser/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/bin/python
ERROR: The executable /Users/myuser/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6' (should be '/Users/myuser/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

---

**7**  Facepalm

---

Complete contents of my .bash_profile file:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave

PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

I'm guessing my issue has to do with the following, but I have no idea what that means nor how to fix it, could someone please help me out?

```
ERROR: The executable /Users/myuser/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6' (should be '/Users/myuser/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: try changing `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3` to `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=\`which python\``

Comment: Hey @KevinL. Thanks for that, I updated my post because I actually tried several variants of that, to no avail.

Comment: try upgrading virtualenv

Comment: Hey Kevin, I think that was the issue. Honestly, I tried a few things without really keep track of what I did exactly, but I'm just going to go with it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think that running the following fixed my issue:

```
pip3 install --upgrade virtualenv
```

Answer (score 0):

Good that you managed to solve the issue.

Having used `mkvirtualenv` for a while though, I recommend that you try `Pipenv` if you haven’t already.

`Pipenv` records the python version that you are using in your virtualenv whereas `virtualenvwrapper` (via `pip freeze`) doesn’t.